# Excel/VBA DB2 Timeout statement

Tags: excel, timeout, db2, vba

I'm connecting to a DB2 database through Excel VBA with the code below.  However, I've tried researching on connectionstrings.com as well as other websites the proper syntax for turning off the timeout so that I do not receive the "User Cancelled Operation" if the query takes a certain amount of time.  Right now, I'm using "Timeout=0", but I still get the error if my query contains more than 3,000 people.  Does anybody know the proper syntax to turn off the timeout?

```
With cn
.ConnectionString = "Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};"
 & "DBALIAS=" & Range(db_alias_range) & ";UID=" & username & ";PWD=" & Range(password_range) & ";Timeout=0;"
.Open
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the IBM documentation for DB2 LUW version. It doesn't contain the keyword `Timeout`. You might want to use `ReceiveTimeout`. Check also all the other timeout options.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0007964.htm

Comment: QueryTimeoutInterval determines how frequently the driver checks for the timeout condition. To determine the timeout threshold use the ReceiveTimeout keyword (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0020996.html) in the cli.ini file, or the corresponding key in db2dsdriver.xml, depending on your DB2 version.

Comment: @mustaccio: To be honest, I was to lazy to read through all timeout definitions. Just trying to give Don an idea on where to look. -- Updated my post thanks.

Comment: QueryTimeoutInterval did not work, but then I just saw the updated posts.  I"m trying ReceiveTimeout=0 now replacing my original Timeout=0.  I've not made any changes in the .ini file or .xml file, all my changes are happening in the VBA.  It seems like that works.